# Showing $f$ to be an isomorphism between hyperboloid and unit ball models of the hyperbolic plane

Tags: metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\mathbb{W^2} = \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} \mid q(x,x) = -1, x_3 > 0\}$ where $q(x,y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 -x_3y_3$ and $\mathbb{B^2} = \{x \in \mathbb{R^3} \mid x_3 = 0, x_1^2 + x_2^2 < 1\}$.

The metric on $\mathbb{W^2}$ is $g_x(v,w) = q(v,w) $ 
 whereas the metric on $\mathbb{B^2}$ is $g_x(v,w) = \dfrac{4}{(1-\| v\|^2)^2}\langle v,w\rangle_{Euclidean}$

Let $f: \mathbb{W^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{B^2}$ given by requiring that for each $p \in \mathbb{W^2}$ the points $f(p)\in \mathbb{B^2}$ and $p$ are collinear with the point $(0,0,−1)$ (i.e. $f$ is a projection from this point to the plane $\{z= 0\}$).

I have shown that $f(X,Y,Z) = (\dfrac{X}{Z+1}, \dfrac{Y}{Z+1})$.

I have that for a specific chart that:  $Df(p)(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}$, where $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i} \in T_p\mathbb{W^2}, $$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i} \in T_{f(p)}\mathbb{B^2}$.

Now I want to show that $\left<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right>_p = \left<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right>_{f(p)} $.

However, I'm having some difficulty:

$Df(p) = \begin{pmatrix} \dfrac{1}{Z+1} & 0 & \dfrac{-X}{(Z+1)^2} \\   0 & \dfrac{1}{Z+1}&  \dfrac{-Y}{(Z+1)^2} \end{pmatrix}$

so,  $\left<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right>_{f(p)}  = \dfrac{4}{(1 - (\| f(p)\|)^2)^2} \left<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right>_{Euclidean}  $.

I then have $\| f(p)\|^2 = \dfrac{X^2 + Y^2}{(Z+1)^2} = \dfrac{Z^2-1}{(Z+1)^2} = \dfrac{Z-1}{Z+1} $.

And so: $\dfrac{4}{(1 - (\| f(p)\|)^2)^2} = (Z+1)^2 $

$\Rightarrow \dfrac{4}{(1 - (\| f(p)\|)^2)^2} \left<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y_j}\right>_{Euclidean}   \\= (Z+1)^2 \left<Df(p)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, Df(p)\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right>_{Euclidean}$.

However, this doesn't seem to be giving me the $\left<\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}, \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\right>_p$.

I would massively appreciate a hint, or a correction if I've made some huge error. As for the assumed results, I'm fairly certain they're correct.

Comment: Not sure about your calculations, but as far as I understand, you want to prove that $f$ is an isometry between the Minkowski hyperboloid and the Poincaré disk model. Which is a true fact, but the Minkowski hyperboloid uses the Minkowski metric and the Poincare disk model uses the Euclidean metric divided by a function of the distance from the center. I do not see the metrics specified in your problem statement.

Comment: I'm using the following metrics for each space: 
On the Minkowski hyperboloid: $g_x(v,w) = q(v,w)$ as above; On the Poincaré disk model: $g_x(v,w) = \dfrac{4}{(1-\vert\vert x \vert \vert^2)^2} \langle v, w \rangle_{euclidean}$